# Non-deterministic multithread test

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, appdomain, unhandled-exception

I have an extension method. Here it is:

```
public static void BeginInvokeWithAutoEnd(this EventHandler handler, object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
{
    var buffer = handler;
    buffer.BeginInvoke(sender, eventArgs, buffer.EndInvoke, null);
}
```

To test it, there is the following method:

```
[TestMethod]
public void BeginInvokeWithAutoEnd_SubscribedMethodThrowsException_ExceptionCanBeCaught()
{
    var multiThreadTest = new MultiThreadTest(2);//Class that helps to test asynchronous stuff 
    var thrown = false;
    var ex = new Exception("OOoooOOo!");
    EventHandler onHandler = (s, a) => { throw ex; };
    UnhandledExceptionEventHandler currentDomainOnUnhandledException = (s, args) =>
    {
        thrown = args.ExceptionObject.Equals(ex);
        multiThreadTest.Notify();
    };
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += currentDomainOnUnhandledException;

    //Invokes Action from the parameter and waits for multiThreadTest.Notify(); method to be called, otherwise 2 seconds
    multiThreadTest.Act(() => onHandler.BeginInvokeWithAutoEnd(this, EventArgs.Empty));

    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException -= currentDomainOnUnhandledException;
    Assert.IsTrue(thrown);
}
```

The test itself works fine, but it breaks randomly one of other tests I have. When I look at the broken test it is written: `The agent process was stopped while the test was running.`. That means that there was an unhandled exception in another thread, while the broken test was running.

I have no idea how could this happen. Will appreciate any help here.

Comment: Because you are starting work on the thread-pool and not waiting for it to finish.

Comment: @usr could you explain a bit more precisely?
I do actually wait for `multiThreadTest.Notify();`. If that is what you mean.

Comment: BeginInvokeWithAutoEnd never waits and immediately returns. This means that the line where `Act` is called also immediately returns. Is that what you want?

Comment: @usr Method `multiThreadTest.Act(...)` invokes `Action` that it received as a parameter and then waits for `multiThreadTest.Notify();`.

Comment: That makes sense. Post more code, especially Act. What happens when you step through the code with the debugger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was so stupid of me.

Workflow of the test:
-the test is started
-the exception is thrown in another thread (let's call it "Thread X")
-`AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException` is raised
-the test finishes, while "Thread X" still runs and haven't finished throwing exception yet
-"Thread X" throws the exception, while another test is already started

For some unknown reason I thought that subscribing to `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException` will prevent the exception from being thrown. So really stupid of me.

Answer (score 1):

Try checking Event Viewer (Event Viewer -> Windows Logs -> Application) for events with ".Net Runtime" as source. If there are some unhandled exceptions, they should be logged there.